# How to capture an image in android with fixed size?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-image

I used the following code to capture image. Everything works fine, when i capture the image it has 2592x1944 size and the image is captured in landscape mode. Now i want to capture the image with the size of 534x534. I changed this parameter values `params.setPictureSize(534, 534);` Nothing will change. How can i do this. Thanks in advance.

**DgCamActivity.java**

```
public class DgCamActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    private SensorManager sensorManager = null;
    private int orientation;
    private ExifInterface exif;
    private int deviceHeight;
    private Button ibRetake;
    private Button ibUse;
    private Button ibCapture;
    // private FrameLayout flBtnContainer;
    private File sdRoot;
    private String dir;
    private String fileName;
    // private ImageView rotatingImage;
    private int degrees = -1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        // Setting all the path for the image
        sdRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        dir = "/SimpleCamera/";

        // Getting all the needed elements from the layout
        // rotatingImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        ibRetake = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ibRetake);
        ibUse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ibUse);
        ibCapture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ibCapture);
        // flBtnContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.flBtnContainer);

        // Getting the sensor service.
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

        // Selecting the resolution of the Android device so we can create a
        // proportional preview
        Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
                .getDefaultDisplay();
        deviceHeight = display.getHeight();

        // Add a listener to the Capture button
        ibCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
            }
        });

        // Add a listener to the Retake button
        ibRetake.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Deleting the image from the SD card/
                File discardedPhoto = new File(sdRoot, dir + fileName);
                discardedPhoto.delete();

                // Restart the camera preview.
                mCamera.startPreview();

                // Reorganize the buttons on the screen
                // flBtnContainer.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
                ibRetake.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
                ibUse.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
            }
        });

        // Add a listener to the Use button
        ibUse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Everything is saved so we can quit the app.
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createCamera() {
        // Create an instance of Camera
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();

        // Setting the right parameters in the camera
        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
        Log.v("SUPORTED SIZE IS>>>>>.", params.getSupportedPictureSizes() + "");
        Log.v("SUPORTED SIZE IS>>>>>.", sizes.size() + "");
        params.setPictureSize(1600, 1200);
        params.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
        params.setJpegQuality(100);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);

        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
        RelativeLayout preview = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

        // Calculating the width of the preview so it is proportional.
        float widthFloat = (float) (deviceHeight) * 4 / 3;
        int width = Math.round(widthFloat);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        preview.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        preview.addView(mPreview, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        createCamera();

        sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        releaseCamera();
        RelativeLayout preview = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.removeViewAt(0);
    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.release(); // release the camera for other applications
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    public static Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            // attempt to get a Camera instance
            c = Camera.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }

        // returns null if camera is unavailable
        return c;
    }

    private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            ibRetake.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ibUse.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // File name of the image that we just took.
            fileName = "IMG_"
                    + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                            .format(new Date()).toString() + ".jpg";

            File mkDir = new File(sdRoot, dir);
            mkDir.mkdirs();

            // Main file where to save the data that we recive from the camera
            File pictureFile = new File(sdRoot, dir + fileName);

            try {
                FileOutputStream purge = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                purge.write(data);
                purge.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d("DG_DEBUG", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("DG_DEBUG", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            try {
                exif = new ExifInterface("/sdcard/" + dir + fileName);
                exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ""
                        + orientation);
                exif.saveAttributes();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };

    /**
     * Putting in place a listener so we can get the sensor data only when
     * something changes.
     */
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
                RotateAnimation animation = null;
                if (event.values[0] < 4 && event.values[0] > -4) {
                    if (event.values[1] > 0
                            && orientation != ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
                        // UP
                        orientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90;
                        animation = getRotateAnimation(270);
                        degrees = 270;
                    } else if (event.values[1] < 0
                            && orientation != ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
                        // UP SIDE DOWN
                        orientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270;
                        animation = getRotateAnimation(90);
                        degrees = 90;
                    }
                } else if (event.values[1] < 4 && event.values[1] > -4) {
                    if (event.values[0] > 0
                            && orientation != ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL) {
                        // LEFT
                        orientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL;
                        animation = getRotateAnimation(0);
                        degrees = 0;
                    } else if (event.values[0] < 0
                            && orientation != ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
                        // RIGHT
                        orientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180;
                        animation = getRotateAnimation(180);
                        degrees = 180;
                    }
                }
                if (animation != null) {
                    // rotatingImage.startAnimation(animation);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    /**
     * Calculating the degrees needed to rotate the image imposed on the button
     * so it is always facing the user in the right direction
     * 
     * @param toDegrees
     * @return
     */
    private RotateAnimation getRotateAnimation(float toDegrees) {
        float compensation = 0;

        if (Math.abs(degrees - toDegrees) > 180) {
            compensation = 360;
        }

        // When the device is being held on the left side (default position for
        // a camera) we need to add, not subtract from the toDegrees.
        if (toDegrees == 0) {
            compensation = -compensation;
        }

        // Creating the animation and the RELATIVE_TO_SELF means that he image
        // will rotate on it center instead of a corner.
        RotateAnimation animation = new RotateAnimation(degrees, toDegrees
                - compensation, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

        // Adding the time needed to rotate the image
        animation.setDuration(250);

        // Set the animation to stop after reaching the desired position. With
        // out this it would return to the original state.
        animation.setFillAfter(true);

        return animation;
    }

    /**
     * STUFF THAT WE DON'T NEED BUT MUST BE HEAR FOR THE COMPILER TO BE HAPPY.
     */
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }
}
```

**CameraPreview.java**

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        mHolder.setSizeFromLayout();
        mHolder.setFixedSize(100, 100);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the
        // preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("DG_DEBUG", "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // make any resize, rotate or reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("DG_DEBUG", "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    }

}
```

**test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="41dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ibCapture"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/camera_preview"
            android:text="Capture" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ibRetake"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ibCapture"
            android:text="ReTake" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ibUse"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
            android:text="Save" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe Android will not allow for arbitrary image sizes when taking a picture, you should use the [parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPictureSizes()) method to query the supported image sizes.

I suspect you would have to choose a big enough size to cut your desired 534x534 patch from. You could do this by using [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) methods to decode the picture that was taken and then use bitmap.getPixels() method to extract the desired patch size, or something like bitmap.createScaledBitmap() to scale your picture to the desired size.

After you have your correctly sized bitmap, you could just use bitmap.compress() to save your image, if that's the final format you are going for.